# jquery in smarty tpl

Tags: jquery, smarty

jquery in smarty tpl -- Trying to use jquery to insert a class attribute so that I can CSS style every other list item row with shading. The following code seems as though it should work, but "alt" class is not getting inserted into li tag. Page loads fine -- no problems there. Anyone see something obviously wrong?

```
{literal}
<script src="{$content_dir}themes/pres2c/js/stripe/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".block_content li:even").addClass("alt");
        });
    </script>
{/literal}
```

this final webpage source is appearing, just like this, in the head, but still li tags aren't getting touched..

```
<script src="{$content_dir}themes/pres2c/js/stripe/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".block_content li:even").addClass("alt");
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: are you sure the jquery is being loaded

Comment: Hi, thanks for message, no, I haven't tested for it, but I have also tried an absolute path to it, so I would imagine it's getting loaded. Can you suggest a test for that?

Comment: place an alert inside the `ready` handler like `jQuery(document).ready(function(){alert("ready to roll");});` and see if that comes up

Comment: yup, dialogue box threw on the alert, so that's good.

Comment: yup thats good, can you post the markup that the php has generated

Comment: I've got to leave the computer for the night. Thanks for helping. I'll be back around tomorrow. FYI -- this is where I found this solution (http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Zebra_Striping_Made_Easy#First_Steps_With_jQuery). I wanted to use jquery because IE8 doesn't support n-th child, for using only CSS to style every other row. I thought this would be easy, as my site runs plenty of jquery, but I must be missing something.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
{literal}
<script src="{/literal}{$content_dir}{literal}themes/pres2c/js/stripe/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".block_content li:even").addClass("alt");
        });
    </script>
{/literal}
```

Comment: don't just paste code, add an explanation of why this might work, and highlight the specific details which are relevant to the asker. Then, supply your code as an example at the end.

Comment: {literal} turns off the tag interpretation, literally, so you need to turn off the literal mode {/literal} before the tag, then turn it back on after the tag {literal}

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
<script src="{$content_dir}themes/pres2c/js/stripe/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
{literal}
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".block_content li:even").addClass("alt");
    });
{/literal}
</script>
```

This way, {$content_dir} is still a smarty variable. In your case, {$content_dir} is taken literal, instead of the variable