# Smarty - How can i add "show more links tab"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, smarty

How can I add "show more links tab" after showing 10-15 links instead of showing 100-200 links? I want to show only 10-15 links at first and then when somebody clicks show the rest of the hidden links to save page space.

```
{if $listing_styles.links}
  <div id="link_list" {if $listing_styles.embeds}style="display:none"{/if}>
    {foreach from=$thisepisode.embeds key=id item=val name=titles}

      <div class="span-16 inner-16 notopmargin embed-selector" style="background: #F1F2F1 url('{$embed_languages[$val.lang].flag}') 15px 17px no-repeat;" onclick="changeEmbed({$val.id},{$global_settings.countdown});">

        <h5 class="left">
          {$embed_languages[$val.lang].language}
          {if $val.type} - 
            <a class="link" href="javascript:void(0);" {if $smarty.foreach.titles.first}class="current"{/if} id="selector{$val.id}"><span>{$val.type}</span></a>
          {/if}
        </h5>

        <ul id="filter" style="width:200px;float:right;margin-top: 0px;">
          {if $val.link}
            {if $global_settings.adfly.id}
              <li class="current" style="float:right">
                <a href="http://**f.ly/{$global_settings.**fly.id}/{$val.link|replace:"http://":""}" target="_blank">{$lang.open_video}</a>
              </li>
          {else}
              <li class="current" style="float:right">
                <a href="{$val.link}" target="_blank">{$lang.open_video}</a>
              </li>
            {/if}
          {/if}
        </ul>
      </div>

    {/foreach}
  </div>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this plugin. Works great for what you want to do:

http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/

Based off your html, here is a fiddle showing this working with the readmore plugin. I've just copied the complete readmore code into the fiddle, but you would probably want to add it as a reference js file (the code from line 8 down in the javascript is the plugin code).

http://jsfiddle.net/6px7qso0/1/

Basically, download and add a reference to the readmore.js file on your page (get the file from github from the link I posted in the comments). Then add the following code to your page.

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('#link_list').readmore({
            speed: 75,
            collapsedHeight: 400,
            lessLink: '<a href="#">Read less</a>'
        });
    });
</script>    
{/literal}
```

Have a look at the plugin options for more control over the plugin.

Comment: tried not working i want it for smarty template engine the above code is smarty.

Comment: Are you passing the link_list div into the readmore plugin? If you still can't get it to work, post the pages source you want the plugin to work with. Not the smarty code, but the actual output HTML.

Comment: https://tvseriesden.com/show/the-returned/season/1/episode/6   CHECK there i want to show only 10 links rest should be hidden under show more. @garethb

Comment: i added a reference to readmore.js in my header.tpl also added `$(function(){
    $('#link_list').readmore({
        speed: 75,
        collapsedHeight: 400
        lessLink: '<a href="#">Read less</a>'
    });
});`  but after that page do not load it totally got blank. @garethb maybe it dont work with smarty ?

Comment: For Smarty, you need to wrap your javascript in {literal}, see updated answer. Also, $ is a special character in Smarty so need to use jQuery instead. Where you add a reference to readmore.js, make sure it is also wrapped in a {literal}. And also add a reference to jquery above the reference to readmore.js if you don't already reference jquery. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12365507/853295 for more help on including javascript in Smarty.

Comment: still not working  added readmore.js reference into my header.tpl aswell as added the above of your code to my page where i wanted. It stop showing blank page now but plugin isnt enabled. Check https://tvseriesden.com/show/the-vampire-diaries/season/6/episode/17

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, missed a comma. See updated code. Also, theres an error on this line: <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$("#link_list").shorten();});</script>. You should replace the '$' with 'jQuery'.

Comment: I think it gonna blast my head still not working :( @garethb i really appreciate your help, but what can i do u can refresh the page now and check. code is there but not working.

Comment: It's not working because of something in your main_theme.js that is interfering with the readmore plugin. I can't see for certain what because it's minified, but my guess is there is some code in there that does something with the link_list div that stops readmore from working properly. If you look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kufpff1p/, once you add a reference to your main_theme.js, the readmore plugin stops working.

Comment: Now i removed main_theme and added te originals javescripts which i consolidated and minified to main_theme.js now check if you find any thing.  https://tvseriesden.com/templates/svarog/js/foxycomplete.js https://tvseriesden.com/templates/svarog/js/custom.js   i figure it out these 2 js are interfering with it.  But when i removed both these javascripts from my code still not working tried every single possibility but not working . It is working on fiddle but not on my website strange. @garethb

Comment: OK, got it working on your site. Add a <div class="clearfix"></div> INSIDE the link_list div at the very end (just before the link_list closing div tag). Because you're floating all the child elements inside the link_list div, the link_list div has no height so readmore can't minimise something with no height. adding the clearfix in there gives the link_list the correct height so readmore can do its calculations correctly. A parent element will 'ignore' any floated children.

Comment: P.S. Only helping you out so much since I'm going to start using your site! :)

Comment: OMG it worked finally :) thank you so much, and that's awesome you can tell me which show you like i will update that for you :)